# How to set up Django i18n on Google App Engine (GAE)?

Tags: python-3.x, django, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, django-i18n

Using Django 4.0.2, and GAE standard, the site text does not change when a language is selected. The main language is english. The second language is Dutch. If I switch the language, then the url changes and includes `/nl` instead of `en/`, but the English text remains. On localhost, the English text is replaced with the Dutch text.

I'm using [django-rosetta](https://django-rosetta.readthedocs.io/) and on GAE its dashboard finds two instances of my application, called `workspace/` and `srv/`. Each contains the same `.mo` file in the same location `/workspace/locale/nl/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`. I dont know why there are two applications, or if this is relevant. On localhost, I have one application in the expected location.

There are no errors, and checking the existence of the `.mo` file returns `True`.

My `locale` directory is in the project root. On local this is my project name, on GAE the name of the project root directory is `workspace`. This should be fine because building file paths using `ROOT_DIR` still works as expected for locale settings and also all other settings.

The relevant settings are:

```py
ROOT_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent.parent

_locale_dir = ROOT_DIR / "locale"
_locale_file = _locale_dir / "nl/LC_MESSAGES/django.po"
print(f"--- {_locale_file.is_file() = }")

LOCALE_PATHS = [ROOT_DIR / "locale", "/workspace/locale", "/srv/locale"]
APPS_DIR = ROOT_DIR / "lettergun"

TIME_ZONE = "CET"
LANGUAGE_CODE = "en"
USE_I18N = True
# USE_L10N = True # Deprecated in Django 4
USE_TZ = True
LOCALE_PATHS = [ROOT_DIR / "locale", "/workspace/locale", "/srv/locale"]

LANGUAGES = (
    ("en", _("English")),
    ("nl", _("Dutch")),
)

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    ...
]

# TRANSLATION USING ROSETTA
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ROSETTA_MESSAGES_PER_PAGE = 20
ROSETTA_ENABLE_TRANSLATION_SUGGESTIONS = True
DEEPL_AUTH_KEY = "e3b5c854-f059-2f86-6ebb-5eeafc3c57a6"
ROSETTA_LANGUAGE_GROUPS = True
ROSETTA_SHOW_AT_ADMIN_PANEL = True
```

url config

```py
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns: URLList = i18n_patterns(
    # base app
    path("", include("lettergun.apps.base.urls", namespace="base")),
    path("blog/", include(wagtail_urls)),
... etc
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += [
    # API base url
    path("api/", include("config.api_router")),
    # DRF auth token
    path("auth-token/", obtain_auth_token),
]
```

Template example

```html
{% load i18n %}

...

      {% get_current_language as CURRENT_LANGUAGE %}
      {% get_available_languages as AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES %}
      {% get_language_info_list for AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES as languages %}

...
    {% for language in languages %}
    <span class="inline-block">
      <a class=" {% if language.code == CURRENT_LANGUAGE %} font-bold {% endif %}  px-1" href="/{{ language.code }}/">
        {% if language.name_local == "English" %} EN {% elif language.name_local == "Nederlands" %} NL {% endif %}
      </a>
    </span>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by an auto-generated `.gcloudignore` file including `.mo` files.

If the catalog file is missing, Django wont raise an error.